# selecting the top record in sql table

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a a table with date field and recordid field.
The recordid field has records like 10001 10002 11152 etc.. These id's are repeated as per the date field. 
I want to pick up each recordid once with the maximum date for that recordid.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT recordid, MAX(Date) From yourTable
GROUP By recordid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT recordid,MAX(date) FROM table GROUP BY recordid;
```

Comment: That'll only work on MySQL and SQLite -- most others require a `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: makes no sense. where's the groupby?

Comment: D'oh. I didn't even realize that would work in MySQL or SQLite... it was just a total brainfart.

Comment: It's actually ANSI that a GROUP BY isn't necessary, but that's not how most vendors implemented it.  For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: @OMG: I don't know what the original answer was but `SELECT recordid, MAX(date) FROM table` is not valid in MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX` and group by `recordid`

```
SELECT  recordid
       ,MAX(date) 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY recordid
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
Select * 
from your_table
inner join (
    SELECT recordid, date=MAX(Date) From yourTable
    GROUP By recordid) as m
  on your_table.recordid=m.recordid
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

`select * from your_table where date = (select max(date) from your_table yt)`